# How to do URL encoding of value which is already in %

Tags: java, url, encoding, uri, urlencode

I have to ask input from user and then do encoding for input.
user input : ABC!123%C56
expected output: ! and % symbol should be encoded but ! symbol got encoded and % symbol didn't encode because %C is already value of some other symbol.please suggest solution how to use encoding with % symbol.

Comment: show us the code that you used for encoding

Comment: My question is can we do encoding of %C ?

Comment: Sure you can. The encoding for "%C" is "%25C". If your code doesn't encode it like this your code is wrong. What is wrong with your code is hard to say as long as you don't show your code.

Comment: According to https://www.urlencoder.org/ your user input "ABC!123%C56" should be encoded as "ABC%21123%25C56". If your code does something else then it is **not doing** URL encoding

Answer (score -1):

You can match whether`%` is contained in the symbol entered by the user. If it contains `%` , you can replace`%` with a special symbol (the symbol that the user does not normally enter). Try to avoid selecting the symbols that users will use. For example, `<p>` stands for percent. I think the `<p>` symbol is rarely used. If you need to decode it, replace `<p>` with `%` .

> for example: `ABC!123%C56 --> ABC!123<p>C56`

Comment: It's not working. I took input from user James%00009 and after encoding it's James<p>00009 but it's not working.

Any other method to encode %(A-F), %(0-9) because rest are working fine.

Comment: Downvoted because your solution does not do URL encoding but some other arbitrary encoding.